# add amount to shipping cost per product

Tags: rules, commerce

I have some products type , I want when  a specify product type is in order add amount to shipping cost.
my idea was  create a rule with condition `Order contains products of particular product types`  ,and select action `add a amount to unit price` but  in  `item identifier *
Specify an identifier of a commerce Line item` section I try everything but returned me error.

I try `commerce-order:commerce-line-items:` and `commerce-order:commerce-line-items:0`,`commerce-order:commerce-line-items:1` ,`commerce-order:commerce-order-total:`

but all of them return me **Data selector commerce-order:commerce-line-items: for parameter commerce_line_item is invalid.** error.

what I should input there ? is my idea correct way to add amount to shipping price when specify products are in order?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably wanting the basic solution explained in this video: https://commerceguys.com/blog/using-calculation-rules-add-item-shipping-commerce-shipping-screencast

With a little modification, it looks like this:

1. Add a new "Calculation rule" for your shipping service.
2. Add an action loop that loops through the line items in the order.
3. Add an action "Calculate a value" and multiply the quantity times a field which holds the shipping price you want to charge for that item and store it in a named variable.
4. Add an action "Add an amount to the unit price" that adds the named variable to the unit price of the shipping line item.

Comment: Using the Commerce Flat Rate module to create a rate for each product. How would I then create another shipping service with the value calculated from the commerce_shipping_price field?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the [Commerce Flat Rate](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate) module to add a flat rate to each item. You can also specify a standard rate for the first item, and an additional cost per extra item.

Comment: I have this module install, I want to specify product has specified flat rate .